# What does a jet engine technician do?

Tags: jet-engine, aircraft-maintenance

I know that they repair everything that concerns engines, but what is the actual day for them. Do they sit in the factories or work in airports?

Comment: @mins After years of training, [this guy](https://youtu.be/5FsrNEeqd6Q) has the technique down

Comment: @mins Fortunately, as bad as that looks, that guy was not seriously injured. Apparently a strap caught on something before he reached the fan.

Comment: @TomMcW: Ah that's indeed completely different :) Lucky man!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You ask a very broad question. Jet engine technicians can work in various capacities depending on the job they are hired to do.

In my experience, I worked on the flight-line directly on aircraft removing/installing, performing operational checks, troubleshooting and servicing engines and other systems.

Some technicians work on engines out of the aircraft and in a controlled environment like the factories where engines are made. Others work in repair shops tearing down and rebuilding existing engines.